# Poor performance moving several image concurrently issue using UIImageView alloc

Tags: ios, objective-c

so here is the problem I encounter, my app has several images(50x50 ~ 150x150) store in a NSMutableArray, each image is moving from x1,y1 to x1+i,y1+i (i+=1) in a for loop triggered by a timer calling every 0.02 second. it runs smooth on the simulator but iphone, what shall I suppose to do?? Is there any efficient way without using Cocos2d or OpenGL??

```
enter code here

for (int i=0; i <10; i++)             
{ 
    imgImageView = [imgImageArray objectAtIndex:i];
    imgImageView.center = CGPointMake(current_x+1, current_y+1);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to move animated some imageView's? Why no to use UIView animations?

Comment: the images will move until they reach destination, they are triggered by a timer calling the for loop...

Answer (score 0):

Use the UIView animation methods.  That is what they are there for.  For example:  [+ [UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3aanimations%3a)